# Multi-lining an input text field

Tags: jtextfield

I have extended the width and height of the input text field with style. But I need to get it multiple rows instead or one? How do I either:
- Add multiple rows?
- or change the input field type to a normal expandable text field?

~  J

Answer (score 1):

Use `JTextArea`. You might need to set scrolling and text wrapping options to get it to behave the way you want.